# rails named scope to merge fields full name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `first_name` and a `last_name` field in my `Author` model. Sometimes I need to output the full name so I was thinking of a named scope `:full_name`.

I tried:

`scope :full_name, lambda {"#{first_name} #{last_name}"}`

but when I call `.full_name` on an author instance I get an undefined error message. How come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scopes are used on relations, to build SQL query, like this:

```
scope :newest, -> { order('created_at DESC').limit(10) }
Author.newest
# => returns relation of author records in `created_at DESC` order and limited to 10
```

Instead, you need instance method, which is called on instance:

```
def full_name
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end

author = Author.new(first_name: 'Killer', last_name: 'Pixler')
author.full_name
# => "Killer Pixler"
```

Comment: let's say I want to validate the uniqueness of the full_name in my model. How do I do that? `validates_uniqueness_of :full_name` doesn't work. Some users will have the same first or last name but the full name should be unique

Comment: You can do: `validates_uniqueness_of :first_name, scope: :last_name`.